# how to draw a chord with some specific CSV data

Tags: csv, d3.js, chord-diagram

I am focusing on example https://github.com/sghall/d3-chord-diagrams/blob/master/trade-p.html and it is using data in csv format which is here https://github.com/sghall/d3-chord-diagrams/blob/master/data/trade.csv what i want is to draw chord from same data but when importer1===Panama only.
Can anyone help me i am new to d3 and did not know how to extract specifc data from csv file as i am trying 
if(importer1===Panama)
{draw chords....

}

but its not working.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple use filters as shown below this will filter record for Panama

```
 d3.csv('trade.csv', function (error, data) {
        var data = data.filter(function(d){ return d.importer1 == "Panama"});
        var mpr = chordMpr(data);
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kITXW2I1sNHDUsIbFDb5?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a million Cyril. It works :). Do you have any idea that in the current example chord is in circle shape. What if i want to create same chord in oval shape.

Comment: No Idea how to make it an ellipse

Comment: Cyril i wanted to ask one more thing that if i wanted to create two chords from same data one d3.csv('trade.csv', function (error, data) {
        var data = data.filter(function(d){ return d.importer1 == "Panama"});
        var mpr = chordMpr(data); and the other is d3.csv('trade.csv', function (error, data) {
        var data = data.filter(function(d){ return d.importer1 == "Pakistan"});
        var mpr = chordMpr(data); so how it works as i am trying to put if statement but it does not works.thanks in advance

Comment: @Sam you can do some thing like this ryt _var data = data.filter(function(d){ return (d.importer1 == "Panama" || d.importer1 == "Pakistan")});_

Comment: I need to draw two chords :) with different importer1 values on same page...But thanks for your suggestion